# How can I search an entire database in Python's sqlite3?

Tags: python, search, sqlite

New to sqlite3... I have constructed a database in python using sqlite3.  The database has hundreds of tables.  A sample table lists, say, the average age of people as a function of latitude and longitude. What command can I use to search the entire database (all tables) for "Avg. Age" values where lat > 15, and lon < 30?  Sample tables are as follows:

Table 1:

```
_Avg. age_|__Latitude__|__Longitude__
     15   |    19.86   |     21.5
     21   |    19.86   |     21.5
     75   |    19.86   |     21.5
     16   |    19.86   |     21.5
     .    |      .     |       . 
     .    |      .     |       . 
     .    |      .     |       .
```

Table 2:

```
_Avg. age_|__Latitude__|__Longitude__
     75   |   -22.65   |     53.5
     65   |   -22.65   |     53.5
     12   |   -22.65   |     53.5
     31   |   -22.65   |     53.5
     16   |    19.86   |     53.5
     .    |      .     |       . 
     .    |      .     |       . 
     .    |      .     |       .
```

Comment: _"What command can I use to search the entire database (all tables) for"_ You should not need to do this. Tables should not be created dynamically. Replace whatever information that was in your table name with a column in a single table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to iterate over all the tables and select from each one

```
for table in db.execute("SELECT name FROM my_db.sqlite_master WHERE type='table'").fetchall():
    print db.execute("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE lat > 15  and lon < 30"%table).fetchall()
```

I guess

Comment: On windows, `my_db.sqlite_master` becomes `sqlite_master`. Additionally, I needed explicitly define my conn=sqlite3.connect filepath.

Comment: of coarse ... this answer assumes you have some basic understanding of how to connect to a sqlite3 database ...